# "Active quantum fluctuations" due to the quantization of the gravitational field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, terminology, quantum-gravity, foundations

This is a follow-up to the question [In what sense is the word quantum fluctuation used here?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/668107/233512)

---

In [arXiv:0710.3787](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3787v1) it is stated on page 7 that there are "*active fluctuations in the intrinsic degrees of freedom of gravity*" and on page 13 that "*Quantum stress tensor fluctuations lead to passive fluctuations of the gravitational field, which are in addition to the active fluctuations coming from the quantization of the gravitational field itself.*"

---

I will once again give my definition of quantum fluctuations:

"Quantum fluctuation" is an informal name for the fact that: In any quantum mechanical system with states in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, if you have a self-adjoint linear (densely defined, maybe?) operator $$\hat{\mathcal{O}}:\mathcal H\supset D(\hat{\mathcal O})\to\mathcal H$$ corresponding to some observable $\mathcal O$ and a state $\vert\psi\rangle\in\mathcal H$ which is not an eigenvector of $\hat{\mathcal O}$, then performing the same measurement on a physical system in the state $\vert\psi\rangle$ will lead to different results. For further discussion of my understanding see [[1]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257035/233512), [[2]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382917/233512), [[3]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146003/233512), [[4]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16851/233512). In particular, the word "fluctuation" is misleading since the above fact need not have anything to do with a change in time (or space).

---

Now, what do the "active fluctuations" in the quoted text blocks above refer to? Are they fluctuations in my sense? Are they something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "fluctuations" language is addressed in [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/668121) to the previous question, so in this answer I'll only address the "active" and "passive" language.

In classical general relativity, the metric is still dynamic even when/where the stress-energy tensor is zero, which is why gravitational waves are possible. "Active quantum fluctuations" refers to quantum fluctuations in those gravitational-wave degrees of freedom. "Passive" refers to fluctuations in the rest of the metric degrees of freedom, those that are tied to fluctuations in the stress-energy tensor as shown in equation (1) of [arXiv:1703.05331](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05331).

Comment: For completeness, I will state the general-relativity-property that you mention here (please correct me if I made a mistake or understood you incorrectly): The Einstein field equations (EFE) with $\Lambda=0$ and $T=0$ are $$Rc-\frac12Sg=0.$$ Multiplying the $i,j$-th equation with $g^{j,i}$ and summing over $i,j$ yields $$\sum_{i,j=1}^4Rc_{i,j}g^{j,i}-\frac12Sg_{i,j}g^{j,i}=0,$$ which (exercise for the reader), is the same as $$S-2S =0.$$ Thus, $S=0$. Putting this into EFE gives $Rc=0$. But $Rc=0$ doesn't imply Riemannian curvature$=0$, so there are still non-trivial EFE solutions with $T=0$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  That's all correct.